# Selecting specific table in a document using Google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google Document that contains some text, images, and tables. I need to get one specific table to edit (Append Rows) using Appscript. How can I do it?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE : 
I made this workaround :

```
 var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var range = body.findText("#PLACEHOLDER#");
  var table = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE, range);
```

Add **#PLACEHOLDER#** Text just before the table in the document, it can be deleted later.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```js
function appendtable() {
 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody(),
      searchElement = body.findElement(DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE),
      element = searchElement.getElement(),
      table = element.asTable();
      table.appendTableRow().appendTableCell();

}
```